# Prevent google from showing site for specific keyword

Tags: google-search

I have a client who recently changed their website and removed some text containing a former employee's name from the site (around a month ago).
Now they wish for the website not to show up on google when someone searches for that former employee.

I tried the Google Web Developer tools to crawl the site and send it to the index again, but the one page is still showing. I am not sure what else I can do to get rid of this entry, but am wondering if there is a way to kinda "block" certain keywords, so that a page doesn't show up if that keyword is searched on google.
Is there a way for that? Or a way to have google removing this entry from the search results for that keyword?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question..?  (and I'm pretty sure the answer to your question is "no", once it's on the net it's there 'forever').

Comment: No it isn't. Please let me know where I should ask these kinds of questions.

Comment: Perhaps http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ would have more people "in-the-know"..?

Comment: Can questions be moved?

Answer (score 1):

I would try removing the old cached page at least.  From Google's [Webmaster Tools](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663691) site:

1. Go to the [Google public URL removal tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals).
2. Click **New removal request**.
3. Type the URL of the webpage that's been changed (not the Google search results URL or cached page URL). The URL is case-sensitive—use exactly the same characters and capitalization that the site uses. [How to find the right URL](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/63758).
4. Click **Continue**.
5. Type a word that appears on the out-of-date cached version of the page, but not   anywhere on the live version. This is to help Google understand that the page has changed.

   It’s often more effective to type a single word rather than a phrase. Don’t describe the removed content or the changes made; instead, explicitly provide a word that was in the old version but is missing from the new. For example, the cached page might contain your name, which has since been removed from the live version. In this case, don’t tell us that "my name has been removed'; instead, type your actual name ("Sylvia") as it appears in the cached version.
6. Click **Remove cache**.

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna try and report back my results.

Comment: That didn't work. I'm sure it would do fine, but the site didn't seem to have a cached version in the first place. 
The request was denied but said that it will be removed after the next crawl. I actually thought I requested a new crawl and that that happened, but the site still shows.. I guess they'll just have to wait then..?